# i can't get cookie anymore

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, fetch

I build a server with nodeJs 、 Express4.x and express-session  MeanWhile I Use the global Fetch on frontEnd

The tourble that I can get the req.cookies anymore expect in the first connection

I thought it was strange

Show the first connection network

[image]

You can see It have Cookie content

However , When I  make a post request (/setSession)

It haven't Cookie content

[image]

this is my server code

[image]

this is the frontEnd code

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) documentation, I would like to remind you for version `1.5.0` or greater

> **Note:** Session data is not saved in the cookie itself, just the session
>   ID. Session data is stored server-side.
>
> **Note:** Since version 1.5.0, the [cookie-parser middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser) no longer needs
>   to be used for this module to work. This module now directly reads and
>   writes cookies on req/res. Using cookie-parser may result in issues if
>   the secret is not the same between this module and cookie-parser.
>
> **Warning:** The default server-side session storage, MemoryStore, is
>   purposely not designed for a production environment. It will leak
>   memory under most conditions, does not scale past a single process,
>   and is meant for debugging and developing.
>
> For a list of stores, see compatible session stores.

So you should use separate secret for [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) and [cookie-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser)

Comment: could please show me some code? I try your method , but It likely hasn't any effect